# How to remove leading character from a specific column in a pipe delimited file?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a pipe delimited text file like this

```
TEST|F123433|F123433|TEST
TEST|F123434|F123434|TEST
TEST|F123435|F123435|TEST
TEST|F123436|F123436|TEST
TEST|F123437|F123437|TEST
```

I am trying to remove leading 'F' from column 2 and 3. Here is the expected output.

```
TEST|123433|123433|TEST
TEST|123434|123434|TEST
TEST|123435|123435|TEST
TEST|123436|123436|TEST
TEST|123437|123437|TEST
```

I tried to do it using sed as below but it removes 'F' only from column 2 but not column 3

```
sed 's/^TEST|F/TEST|/g'
```

Comment: Come up with a more truly representative example that a potential solution could be tested against to see if it works or not. `sed 's/F//g'` would produce your posted output from your posted input so it's presumably not a good test case since it can't be used to distinguish between working and non-working solutions given your stated requirements.

Comment: You just need to escape `|` with a backslash. It's a special character in regular expressions.

Comment: @miken32 Actually in (legacy) `sed` it's the other way around; backslashing the pipe will *turn it into*  a metacharacter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try simple `awk` too. Using `sub` function of it for 2nd and 3rd fields.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {sub(/^F/,"",$2);sub(/^F/,"",$3)} 1'  Input_file
TEST|123433|123433|TEST
TEST|123434|123434|TEST
TEST|123435|123435|TEST
TEST|123436|123436|TEST
TEST|123437|123437|TEST
```

Answer (score 4):

With `sed` (and this only applies to the example as stated) you can globally replace `|F` with `|`:

```
$ sed -E 's/\|F/\|/g' file
```

You can limit to the first two instances of `|F` (not necessarily column numbers) with two non-global substitutions with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\|F/\|/' -e 's/\|F/\|/' file
```

or, in ERE form:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^|]*)\|F/\1|/; s/([^|]*)\|F/\1|/' file
```

---

A better and more flexible field-by-field solution with `awk` allows you to specify which column:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=2; i<=3;i++)sub(/^F/,"",$i);}1' file
TEST|123433|123433|TEST
TEST|123434|123434|TEST
TEST|123435|123435|TEST
TEST|123436|123436|TEST
TEST|123437|123437|TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capture group to copy everything in the 2nd column after the `F`.

```
sed 's/^TEST|F\([^|]*\)|F/TEST|\1|/'
```

There's no need to use the `g` modifier since you're only doing one replacement per line (and a pattern anchored with `^` or `$` can only match once anyway).

Comment: I forgot the `/` at the end

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, using capture groups:

```
sed -E -n 's/^(TEST\|)F(.*)F(.*)/\1\2\3/p'
```

Output:

```
TEST|123433|123433|TEST
TEST|123434|123434|TEST
TEST|123435|123435|TEST
TEST|123436|123436|TEST
TEST|123437|123437|TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(F|([^F|]?))([^|]*)/\2\3/2;s/(F|([^F|]?))([^|]*)/\2\3/3' file
```

This removes the first character `F` of a column delimited by a `|`'s for columns two and three. It uses the fact that an unmatched back reference is empty and thus using such a reference in the RHS of a substitution will effectively remove a previous match.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\|F/,"|")}1' file

TEST|123433|123433|TEST
TEST|123434|123434|TEST
TEST|123435|123435|TEST
TEST|123436|123436|TEST
TEST|123437|123437|TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat > bala.txt
TEST|F123433|F123433|TEST
TEST|F123434|F123434|TEST
TEST|F123435|F123435|TEST
TEST|F123436|F123436|TEST
TEST|F123437|F123437|TEST

$ perl -F"[|]" -lane ' s/^.// for @F[1..2] ; print join("|",@F) ' bala.txt
TEST|123433|123433|TEST
TEST|123434|123434|TEST
TEST|123435|123435|TEST
TEST|123436|123436|TEST
TEST|123437|123437|TEST
```